# Accessing wireless devices through wired connection

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

Im confused, because if i do the command: "nmap -sS -O 192.168.1.254/24" i get a list of all the wireless devices as well as wired. I can also run a webserver on my wired connection and it can be accessed by all the wireless devices. Now my question is, why cant I get results of arp poisoning from wireless devices. I setup a Man in the Middle attack using sslstrip and targeting wireless devices doesnt give me a response.

Comment: I have had better luck testing ARP Poisoning against my local network with wired connections.

Comment: if you're in the security industry or sufficiently expert, then perhaps you might be able to ask on security.stackexchange.com